# SharePoint 2010 Group calendars. How to show all resources by default?

Tags: 2010

When you activate Group Work Lists feature in a site you get the resources list and a few other lists.

If you had the resources list to a page then you can see the list and you have to add each resource list to the page using the resources link.

What I would like to do is have the resources already included on the page when a user visits the site. So if I have 3 Digital cameras, you can see the bookings for those cameras by defualt without having to add each one as a resource.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Does that clarify the situation any better? I will try and add screenshots as soon as I can

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but having just found a great workaround in the Microsoft social forum, I wanted to share it here (the original post can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0833985b-e9ec-4732-a66f-529969203425/view-all-resources-on-a-sharepoint-group-calendar-by-default?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)):

Here is how I managed to get around the issue with the resource reservation calendar:

1. Create a new Group Calendar. In the More Options select "Use this calendar for resource reservations"
2. Once the calendar is created, go into the Calendar list settings. Click Title Description and Navigation. Set "Use this calendar for resource reservation" to no.
3. While in the calendar list settings, Click Change new button order and default content type. Check "Reservations" and set it to the default content type.

When you go back to the calendar it will just have the normal calendar ribbon without the buggy resource selection options. When you add a new list item, the calendar will be associated to the resource list and let you select the resources and detect their availability.
Moreover, in the normal day, week or month view, you will see all the reservations made. If you set a convention in naming the title of an event, you can easily see what resource each event is tied to.

Comment: This is the best solution by far as it requires no additional javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think this hooks into the resources mailboxes in later versions of MS Exchange, but I could be wrong.

Comment: How do I pull all the resource mailboxes from Exchange server and display in Resources list in Group Calendar list?

Answer (score 1):

Later then 2010 Jimmy? 
The thing is you can add the resources using the button which must be a little javascript or something so if I can mimick that action then I could haave all the resources preload when the page is opened. Know the process and not the theory, always the case :)

Matt

Comment: Not entirely certain, just a guess, but I reckon it's the Resource Mailboxes in 2010. Could try making a couple in the backend and see if it appears when you hit the add resources button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint Group like "Staff" and add the members that you need to that group make sure domain users has permissions for this group as well so that any user can use the group.  Then you just type Staff in the resources text box and the ten resources get added.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is a POST to an .ashx page for every resource you add. Only solution I see is to build a custom webpart which renders a form for every resource, method=POST, action=the specific URL to the .ashx page, including all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post was created quite a while ago but I will post my recommendation in case someone else comes looking...

I may be misunderstanding the question but there seems to be a simpler solution if all you want to do is look at a calendar and see what resources are being used.  One way is to create a new view and make the title of the event be the resources column instead of the 'title' column.

If you use a week view instead of month view, you could actually assign the resources to be the subheading instead of the title so you could still see the actual name of the event too.

Another way is using the Week Group view where you can add resources at the bottom to view their availability throughout the week before you add events.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for an answer, please visit blog post here:

http://zepeda-mcmillan.blogspot.com/2011/03/displaying-default-resources-on-group.html

I just encountered the same issue, and decided to come up with a workaround until MS fixes it.

Comment: Please avoid link only answers